# How many $3$ member subsets $\{x, y, z\}$ of positive natural numbers have the sum $x + y + z = 100$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have a math homework problem where I think I have to use Permutation/Combination.

The question is: How many $3$ member subsets $\{x, y, z\}$ of positive natural numbers have the sum $x + y + z = 100$?

I am trying to use the stars and bars method, so there would be $2$ bars ($1$ less than the number of variables) and $100$ stars.

So is my final answer simply $\binom{102}{100} = 5151$?

Feedback would be appreciated :):)

Also, if this is correct, how would I take my answer a step further and find a solution where I don't include zero?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  What you calculated was the number of solutions of the equation in the nonnegative integers.  Juan Theron has explained how to calculate the number of solutions in the postive integers in his answer.

Comment: No worries, Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you already know the more general stars and bars formula, there is a simple way to convert it to that form.

To force positive integers, set $X = x-1, Y = y-1, Z = z-1,$ so now you have

$X + Y + Z = 97$ for non-negative values of $X,Y,Z$

and the formula yields $\dbinom{99}{97} or \dbinom{99}{2}$ according to your preference

Answer (score 3):

Here order of the summation is not counted since we need the number of sets of three numbers with sum equal to 100. That is, $10+70+20$ and $10+20+70$ both lead to the same set $\{10,20,70\}$. Hence we need to count the 3 partitions of 100. We can use the recurrence
$$P(n,k) = P(n-k,k)+P(n-1,k-1)$$ where $P(n,k)$ denotes the $k$ partition of $n$. We need $P(100,3)$. Using the above recurrence and the facts that $P(2m,2) = P(2m+1,2) = m$, it is seen that $P(100,3) = 833$

Answer (score 2):

As you have used star and bar method, you have $100$ chocolates and you have to distribute them to $3$ students such that each student gets at least $1$ chocolate.

So we arrange $100$ chocolates in a row and there is $1$ gap in between $2$ chocolates.

So there is a total of $99$ gaps, and we have to use separators in two of these gaps, which can be done by $\displaystyle \binom{99}{2}$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

Although you answer is almost true, but in the statement of your question is stressed count only $3$ member subset $\{x, y, z\}$, but as you see, you have count $1 + 1 + 98 = 100$ and etc. I think that you should consider this situations. So you should count the number of solutions of equation $x+2y = 100$, then you can suppose that $x = 2k$, and solve the equation $k + y = 50$.

Comment: ok I see my issue and that i am counting repeat values.. i'm still not too sure how i address this